# How to get position of view created programmatically in scrollview placed in cell and cell indexpath in tableview in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7

This is my code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

 CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;

 int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;

 NSLog(@"Page No Scroll %i",page);

}
```

Comment: Your question is quite confusing. What do you want? Are you using a scrollview and creating the views inside it yourself or you are using a tableView and you want the position of a cell at a certain indexPath?

Comment: see simple i have taken an tableview having 4 cell and each cell having scrollview which also having 4 view created dynamically and i want both first is view like paging which is in scrollview selected and shown that no and second is cell indexpath in tableview.. when i scroll left to right which view i currenty see that no and cell indexpath..

Comment: Okkk. Can you show your code where you are creating the tableView cells? And are you using storyboards?

Comment: UIScrollView *Scroll = (UIScrollView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
 Scroll.tag=indexPath.row+1;
  int countplacesize =4;
 Scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake((self.view.frame.size.width*countplacesize)+self.view.frame.size.width, 0);
Scroll.delegate=self;
int setx=5;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
UIView *BackGroundV=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(setx, 8, screenBounds.size.width-10, Scroll.frame.size.height-14)];
 [Scroll addSubview:BackGroundV];
 setx=setx+self.view.frame.size.width;
  }

Comment: I would suggest to use a collectionView in place of a scrollView inside each tableView cell. There are more than one reasons for I'm suggesting that. To better understand the question I would like to ask what exactly do you want to do with the position of the view and when do you want to get it? I mean do you want it when the user taps on it or what?

Comment: see this like  : one array for state and inner scroll having city:  Both :State and city name and id wants : https://www.dropbox.com/s/87cor4eamftl5mc/Screen%20capture%20144.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)ScrollView
{
int scrollPositionX = callerScrollView.contentOffset.x;
if (callerScrollView == tbl_ProductView) return;
 for (UITableViewCell *cell in tbl_ProductView.visibleCells) {
UIScrollView cellScrollView = (UIScrollView )[cell viewWithTag:100];
if (callerScrollView == cellScrollView) continue;
NSInteger indexPath = callerScrollView.tag;
//NSLog(@"IndexPath Of Cell: %ld",(long)indexPath);
cellScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollPositionX, 0);
}
//ScollPage Position
static NSInteger previousPage = 0;
CGFloat pageWidth = callerScrollView.frame.size.width;
float fractionalPage = callerScrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
 NSInteger page = lround(fractionalPage);
  if (previousPage != page)
 {
   previousPage = page;
    NSLog(@"Scrolling Page: %li",(long)page);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get any `subview` by doing this on `UIScrollView`.

```
for(UIView * subView in scrollView.subviews ) 
{ 
     // Here You can Get all subViews of your myScrollView.
}
```

Comment: if i scroll left to right which view i refere selected that no and tableview cell both i get?

Comment: please elaborate your question.

Comment: i have taken an tableview having 4 cell and each cell having scrollview which also having 4 view created dynamically and i want both first is view like paging which is in scrollview selected and shown that no and second is cell indexpath in tableview.. when i scroll left to right which view i currenty see that no and cell indexpath.